# ExtJS 4.1 : How to combine local data with ajax loaded data in a single store?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, store, extjs4.1

I'm looking for a way to combine local data with ajax loaded data in a single store. It's difficult for me to explain this in english, I hope this piece of code will be more explicit :

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoLoad: true,
    fields: ['id', 'name'],
    proxy: { type: 'ajax', api: { read: '/read' }  },
    data: [{ id: 1, name: 'John' }]
});
```

Json returned by "/read" : `[{ id: 2, name: 'Jack' }]`.

Desired behaviour : `store.count() // 2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.load({addRecords: true}` to add loaded records to existing records.

Of course if you load **again** with the `addRecords: true` option enabled it will add the records to the existing records again resulting in:

```
[{ id: 1, name: 'John' },{ id: 2, name: 'Jack' },{ id: 2, name: 'Jack' }]
```

You could implement a before load handler to reset the store to the original data and load again if you want only `[{ id: 1, name: 'John' },{ id: 2, name: 'Jack' }]` every time you load again.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to declare this directly in the config options?

Comment: This might indeed work. The store needs to be set to `autoLoad: false` otherwise a standard load operation will be triggered which has `addRecords: false` by default.

Comment: This doesn't fit exactly with what I was trying to do (`addRecords: true` as a config option), but a single `store.load({ addRecords: true })` just after instanciation is a pretty nice solution. Thanks everyone!