# ExtJS: 2 ajax store, 1 with an extra row

Tags: ajax, extjs, local, store

I have this code:

```
Ext.define('storeBusiness',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true,
    model: 'Business',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read: '../crud/ler_filter.php?db='+database+'&tbl=mercados',
            create: '../crud/criar.php?db='+database+'&tbl=mercados',
            update: '../crud/update.php?db='+database+'&tbl=mercados',
            destroy: '../crud/apagar.php?db='+database+'&tbl=mercados'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'rows'
        },
        writer: {
            type:'json'
        }
    }
});

var storeBusinessCombo = Ext.create('storeBusiness');

var storeBusiness = Ext.create('storeBusiness');

storeBusiness.add({id: 0, business: "All"});
```

I have 2 grids. One has *storeBusiness* and the other has *storeProducts*.
The way the work is when I click on the business grid it filters the produts grid so that it shows the products of that business.
On the business grid it has the *storeBusiness* that it fetches the records from a database. I want to fetch all business from the database and add one more record (named 'All') without writing it to the database.
I dont want to add 'All' to the database because in the Product's grid I want to have a combobox that has all the business (*storeBusinessCombo*) without the 'All' record.
Does anyone has any idea how I can do this?
(the code above isn't doing what I want, *storeBusiness* shows all business without the 'All' in the grid)

**Important:** This works if the *Ext.define('storeBusiness',* has a proxy that is of type: 'memory'

Comment: Add the record after the load is completed.

Comment: this page did it for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408952/extjs-4-1-how-to-combine-local-data-with-ajax-loaded-data-in-a-single-store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this I have done:

1. Put the *Ext.define('storeBusiness',{* to `autoLoad: false,`
2. Put this code:

   ```
   var storeBusinessCombo = Ext.create('storeBusiness', {autoLoad: true});

   var storeBusiness = Ext.create('storeBusiness');

   storeBusiness.on('beforeload', function(){
       storeBusiness.loadData([{id: 0, business: "All"}]);
   }
   ```

   And you should put

   ```
   storeBusiness.load({addRecords: true});
   ```

   when you want to load `storeBusiness`.

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches come to mind:

1. Add the "all" record to the store after load and don't sync so the
   record isn't sent to the server.
2. Use memory proxy, retrieve the
   businesses records via Ajax request and assign them to the store via its data config.

Comment: Thank you. I'm interested in the second aproach. I know how to create a memory proxy store, but how do I assign the retrived records to that store?

Comment: I'm having problem with the ajax request to get all the business from the database. How can I get all the records into a a variable?

Comment: I don't need more help thanks. This page did it for me :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408952/extjs-4-1-how-to-combine-local-data-with-ajax-loaded-data-in-a-single-store